# Comparing time from database and current time retrieved using date() function

Tags: php, mysql

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

$currenttimeminus30=date('H:i:s', strtotime("-30 minutes"));


 $query1=mysql_query("select * from outdoor where latitude='$latitude%' && longitude='$longitude%' && user_id='$userid' && last_updated<$currenttimeminus30");
```

I need to compare whether last_updated < $currenttimeminus30 .last_updated is a field in outdoor table and it is of type time.
last_updated value is like 13:05:11

Comment: not clear .. elaborate more

Comment: What's the type of `last_updated` column?

Comment: You already doing in that query what you are asking for. Where is you problem?

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_* functions, they're effectively deprecated, they'll be removed in a future version, and they have issues with newer versions of mysql.  Switch to mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: The type of this attribute shouldn't be only `time` but `datetime` or `int` for unix timestamp. What happens if a record is updated before two years?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM outdoor 
WHERE latitude = '$latitude%' 
AND longitude = '$longitude%' 
AND user_id = '$userid' 
AND last_updated < TIME($currenttimeminus30)
```

If you will not use different time zones you don't want to create the time with PHP. You can use just an `INTERVAL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM outdoor 
WHERE latitude = '$latitude%' 
AND longitude = '$longitude%' 
AND user_id = '$userid' 
AND last_updated < TIME( NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE )
```

**Notes:**

It's better to use `datetime` as field type. In your case you can get wrong results when the record is updated not today but before some days, months, years etc.

Please, do not use [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) because it is **deprecated**:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.
>   See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> [mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
>
> [PDO::query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: There is time(expr), not time() in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Better use mysql's [INTERVAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
last_updated < time ( now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE )
```

here:

```
$query1=mysql_query("select * from outdoor where latitude='$latitude%' and longitude='$longitude%' and user_id='$userid' and last_updated < time ( now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) )";
```